# Is OkHttp compatible with socket.io?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io, okhttp

I'm working on a project where we're trying to send data from an Android app through OKHttp websockets, and we're trying to receive that data on a nodejs server that's using socket.io. We can't seem to figure out how to receive the messages on the node.js side and I'm wondering if this structure is possible to do.

Comment: What library did you prefer for socket.io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2397) from OkHttp maintainer socket.io leverages websockets but in a non-standard way hence they don't support it.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer, recently i upgrade okhttp to 4.9.0 and socket.io client is on 1.0.0 and it just keep disconenctiong. what could be the issue?